# Call parent function in children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to wrap one component in another and call a function from that "one" component.

```
<Parent>
    <Child1>
    <button
        onClick={
        //toggleSomething
        console.log("Run function `toggleSomething` from parent")
        }
    >
        Change state 1
    </button>
    </Child1>

    <Child2>
    <button
        onClick={
        //toggleSomething
        console.log("Run function `toggleSomething` from parent")
        }
    >
        Change state 2
    </button>
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

and in Parent component I have:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: false
  };

  toggleSomething = () => {
    this.setState({
      something: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="parentClasses">{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here is playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/1ykllwnyq3

There is a solution for that?

Comment: pass your function as a props to child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these responsibilities for these components:

- `Parent`: Take care of the state.
- `Child1` and `Child2`: Generic UI container.
- `App`: Takes care of how the state of `Parent` is rendered.

This can be done using the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) technique.

In the example below, instead of passing an element as a children to `<Parent>`, [a function is passed in instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Parent>
          {toggle => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Child1>
                <button onClick={toggle}>Change state 1</button>
              </Child1>
              <Child2>
                <button onClick={toggle}>Change state 2</button>
              </Child2>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </Parent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: false
  };

  toggleSomething = () => {
    this.setState({
      something: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parentClasses">
        {this.state.something.toString()}
        {this.props.children(this.toggleSomething)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Child1 = props => {
  return <div class="someClasses">{props.children}</div>;
};

const Child2 = props => {
  return <div class="someOtherClasses">{props.children}</div>;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: And this is it. Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Parent>
          <Child1 />
          <Child2 />
        </Parent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: false
  };

  toggleSomething = () => {
    console.log("now toggling !!");
    this.setState({
      something: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const reactChildren = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
    const childrenWithProps = reactChildren.map(element =>
      React.cloneElement(element, {
        toggleSomething: this.toggleSomething
      })
    );
    return <div className="parentClasses">{childrenWithProps}</div>;
  }
}

const Child1 = props => {
  return (
    <div class="someClasses">
      <button
        onClick={
          //toggleSomething
          () => {
            props.toggleSomething();
            console.log("Run function `toggleSomething` from parent");
          }
        }
      >
        Change state 1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};


const Child2 = props => {
  return (
    <div class="someOtherClasses">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          debugger;
          props.toggleSomething();
          console.log("Run function `toggleSomething` from button 2");
        }}
      >
        Change state 2
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>.
```

> Now the content of Child 2 and Child1 can be rendered according to
>   props let say tomorrow, you want something else for Child 2 view.
>   you can change your child Component like this.

```
const Child2 = props => {
      const { RenderView, toggleSomething } = props
      //renderView is your view Component(stateless/statefull)
      return (
      <div class="someOtherClasses">
        {<RenderView toggleSomething={toggleSomething} />}
      </div>
      );
    };
```

How about this approach ?.

Comment: This won't work if I want have dynamic content inside <Child1> and <Child2>

Comment: Yes you are right. Let me edit the answer with a different approach which you can make extensible. The problem is in the parent you have the context of parent component . you cannot access the prop passed to child1 or child2 there. You need to write it as a different component. ANd there you can have  various patterns

Comment: It's still insufficient. It will be used in multiple places so it need to be dynamic. Let's say this <Parent> is a wrapper and <Child1> with <Child2> are sides - left and right. Standard is that Child1 is visible to user, and Child2 is not. If I click on button in Child1 the state of Parent should change and add some CSS to show Child2 and hide Child1. Child2 have also button with same action so you can "go forward" and "go back". Like click "Forgot password" in Child1 and then Child2 appears with form and button to "go back" to Child1. That's why I need to  use it like

`<Child1></Child1>`

Comment: Right now your Child1 and Child2 are not doing anything, just a placeholder. You are just returning props.children. You can render various components with different logic passed as RenderView from any place to Child1 in design mentioned above. You are getting the same behavior basically.. I cannot think of any way of doing it without the changes I  did. i have already mentioned in previous comment why it's not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function, and access it from props.
Clone Element lets you add the prop to all children.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Child1 = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.handler}>test</button>;
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: "nope"
  };

  toggleSomething = () => {
    this.setState({
      something: "yes"
    });
  };

  render() {


    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
      this.props.children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(
          child, { handler: this.toggleSomething }
            )
      );

    return <div className="parentClasses">
    {this.state.something}
      {childrenWithProps}   
    </div>;
  }
}

const App = () => 
    <Parent>
        <Child1/> 
    </Parent>

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The problem is I need to pass content in <Child1> component. There will be form with button and this button should call action. I would use this <Parent> and <Child1> components in multiple places so this needs to be "dynamic".

Comment: My answear: https://pastebin.com/ELekzcgQ

In comment I cant paste code.